# What is an improper batter?

Tags: rules, baseball

I'm a first time little league coach, and this came up in my second game: who is an improper (out-of-order) batter? To keep things simple and fair for my kids, I kept the same batting order from game 1 in game 2 and just picked up where we left off. My 7th batter made the final out of game 1, so I had my 8th batter lead off. The opposing coach argued that we were batting out of order.

Looking at MLB and LL rulebooks, I find that the definition of the proper batter is the batter listed in the lineup after the previous batter. In every inning after the first, the previous batter is the batter that completed the last at bat of the previous inning. The rulebook does not seem to state whom the proper batter is to lead off the 1st inning, and therefore any batter seems to be proper.

So was my team batting out of order to lead off with the 8th hitter and then proceed 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9....? (10 kids on the team, everyone bats, hence the 10 the spot)

Comment: "The rulebook does not seem to state whom the proper batter is to lead off the 1st inning, and therefore any batter seems to be proper." This is an _enormous_ stretch in my opinion - MLB rule 5.04(a)(1) is "Each player of the offensive team shall bat in the order that his name appears in his team’s batting order." - that's pretty obviously meant to include the first name on the lineup card leads off the first innings.

Answer (score 4):

You say that the coach complained.  Did the ump say anything?  Do you formally present lineup cards before either game?

I don't have a copy of little league rules.  In MLB, the leadoff batter must be the batter in the first position on the lineup card presented to the opposing coach and the umpire before the start of the game.

Unless you have some rules in your league that speak to this, there is no connection between games of a double-header.  You would normally be free to make your lineup card for the second game as you wish, and can lead off with any player, including one that was not part of the lineup in a previous game.

So you must lead off the game with the 1st batter, but that person could be anyone on the team.